# How does JVM ensure platform independency across all processor architectures?

Tags: java, c++, jvm, conceptual

In my quest to understand the reasoning to use Java over C++ or vice versa for writing applications, I became stuck on this one point. I watched a video introducing me to Java and they said the reason there is a JVM is because it makes Java portable, meaning it runs on many architectures like phones and stuff without having to write a new compiler for each different CPU OS combo. But people must have to do something to make it compatible with each CPU and OS. I don't see how using a JVM changes anything.

Comment: I think the statement "compilers are expensive" requires some qualification to have any meaning.

Comment: I think you're correct, I edited it.

Comment: It doesn't sound like the video is explaining it very well.

Comment: The JVM essentially *is* a compiler, and modern JVMs are quite complex ones. Sounds like the video producer isn't familiar with the technology.

Comment: Yeah, the video wasn't thorough enough for me, nor could I find the answer anywhere else, which is why I'm here :P

Comment: A JVM largely consists of library code which can be made largely platform-independent. Ignoring HotSpot, JITs, etc., the task of porting to another platforms consists only of implementing the platform-specific parts for that platform. This is indeed much cheaper than implementing a compiler. I don't find the assertion that 'compilers are expensive' even slightly controversial in this context, unless you include script-kiddy tools which aren't relevant to the discussion.

Comment: @EJP - Though a fairer comparison would be "porting the backend of a compiler" - it's unclear why that would be substantially more expensive than porting the platform-specific components of a JVM.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It would indeed be a fairer comparison, but porting library code requires lower (or at least more common) skills than retargeting compiler backends. It doesn't sound like the video has much of a clue about compiler architectures.

Comment: Can anyone give me advice as to how to edit this question such that it is not opinion based? I fail to see how saying what is different about two things is a matter of opinion. I took out the part (see edit) that may have led someone to think the question is opinion based even though it wasn't substantial to the answer of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The initial (BETA) versions of Java were *derided* for being "write once, test everywhere". Improving the quality of the software on the initial platforms (SunOS/Solaris, Windows, Mac, etc) greatly increased its' portability (and *portable software* is inherently easier to port). Currently, there are multiple implementations of Java (IBM, JRockit, etc).

Fundamentally, Java is the *specification* of a virtual machine that executes byte codes; and **not** any particular implementation. Because the byte code is the same across platform the Java compiler doesn't need to be altered to support new platforms. Further, much of the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/) (and, thus, the Oracle JVM) is written in Java. Basically, [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)) Java is simplified compared to bootstrapping a compiler for a "real" CPU architecture<sup>**1**</sup>.

<sup>**1**<sub>Excluding CPUs that [natively execute Java byte code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_processor).</sub></sup>

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but the JVM is most likely written in either C or C++. I have to run the JVM on an architecure. So it doesn't make a difference whether I run Java/JVM on an architecture or straight C/C++. Either way I need a C/C++ compiler written for the architecture.